# how to use "For each" loop in vba?

Tags: vba, excel, foreach, userform

```
Sub Findnext()
Dim Name As String
Dim f As range
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim s As Integer

Name = surname.Value
 'currently only searching one instance...doesn't loop and find the rest
Me.ListBox1.Clear
  Set f = Cells.Find(what:=Name, LookIn:=xlValues)
  Set findnext = f
 With ListBox1   
    Do
    Debug.Print findnext.Address
    Set findnext = Cells.findnext(findnext)
       .AddItem f.Value
       .List(0, 1) = f.Offset(0, 1).Value
       .List(0, 2) = f.Offset(0, 2).Value
       .List(0, 3) = f.Offset(0, 3).Value
       .List(0, 4) = f.Offset(0, 4).Value
       .List(0, 5) = f.Offset(0, 5).Value
       .List(0, 6) = f.Offset(0, 6).Value
  Loop While findnext.Address <> f.Address
  End With
End Sub
```

how do i make this code loop so that it would find multiple f values? essentailly, I have a search button and it promopts "There are 3 instances" and in the list box, it should list out the 3 instances (eg. same name).

I tried using For each f and next f in the code above, but it still only picks one f.value and doesn't pick any other cells with same name....

EDIT:
i've added the loop function but now in the list box, it only lists the person's name instead of listing all the offset values. is the offset not applied to the loop? or is it because it's only looking for f? which is the name it's looking for?

EDIT: The coding I have done so far...

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
MsgBox "Directorate has been added", vbOKOnly

 Dim ctrl As control
   For Each ctrl In UserForm1.Controls
     If TypeName(ctrl) = "CheckBox" Then
       'Pass this CheckBox to the subroutine below:
     TransferValues ctrl
     End If
   Next
```

TransferMasterValue
End Sub

```
Sub TransferValues(cb As MSForms.CheckBox)
 Dim ws As Worksheet 
 Dim emptyRow As Long

If cb Then
   'Define the worksheet based on the CheckBox.Name property:
    Set ws = Sheets(Left(cb.Name, 15))
    emptyRow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(ws.range("A:A")) + 1
       With ws
           .Cells(emptyRow, 1).Value = surname.Value
           .Cells(emptyRow, 2).Value = firstname.Value
           .Cells(emptyRow, 3).Value = tod.Value
           .Cells(emptyRow, 4).Value = program.Value
           .Cells(emptyRow, 5).Value = email.Value
           .Cells(emptyRow, 6).Value = officenumber.Value
           .Cells(emptyRow, 7).Value = cellnumber.Value
        End With

  End If
End Sub

Sub TransferMasterValue()
 Dim allChecks As String
 Dim ws As Worksheet
   'Iterate through the checkboxes concatenating a string of all names
 For Each ctrl In UserForm1.Controls
   If TypeName(ctrl) = "CheckBox" Then
    If ctrl Then
        allChecks = allChecks & ctrl.Name & ""

    End If
   End If
 Next

'If you have at least one transfer to the Master sheet
  If Len(allChecks) > 0 Then
    Set ws1 = Sheets("Master")
    emptyRow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(range("A:A")) + 1

    With ws1
        .Cells(emptyRow, 1).Value = surname.Value
        .Cells(emptyRow, 2).Value = firstname.Value
        .Cells(emptyRow, 3).Value = tod.Value
        .Cells(emptyRow, 4).Value = program.Value
        .Cells(emptyRow, 5).Value = email.Value
        .Cells(emptyRow, 7).Value = officenumber.Value
        .Cells(emptyRow, 8).Value = cellnumber.Value
        .Cells(emptyRow, 6).Value = Left(allChecks, Len(allChecks) - 1)
    End With
  End If
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
 Unload UserForm1
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
 surname.Value = ""
 firstname.Value = ""
 tod.Value = ""
 program.Value = ""
 email.Value = ""
 officenumber.Value = ""
 cellnumber.Value = ""
 PACT.Value = False
 PrinceRupert.Value = False
 WPM.Value = False
 Montreal.Value = False
 TET.Value = False
 TC.Value = False
 US.Value = False
 Other.Value = False
End Sub

Private Sub ListBox1_Click()
 Dim r As Long
 With Me.ListBox1

  With Me
    .surname.Value = .ListBox1.List(.ListBox1.ListIndex, 0)
    .firstname.Value = .ListBox1.List(.ListBox1.ListIndex, 1)
    .tod.Value = .ListBox1.List(.ListBox1.ListIndex, 2)
    .program.Value = .ListBox1.List(.ListBox1.ListIndex, 3)
    .email.Value = .ListBox1.List(.ListBox1.ListIndex, 4)
    .officenumber.Value = .ListBox1.List(.ListBox1.ListIndex, 5)
    .cellnumber.Value = .ListBox1.List(.ListBox1.ListIndex, 6)
  End With
 End With
End Sub

Private Sub Search_Click() 'only searches in master tab right now need to search from all worksheets
 Dim Name As String
 Dim f As range
 Dim r As Long
 Dim ws As Worksheet
 Dim s As Integer
 Dim FirstAddress As String

   Name = surname.Value

     With ws
        Set f = range("A:A").Find(what:=Name, LookIn:=xlValues)
       If Not f Is Nothing Then
     With Me
        firstname.Value = f.Offset(0, 1).Value
        tod.Value = f.Offset(0, 2).Value
        program.Value = f.Offset(0, 3).Value
        email.Value = f.Offset(0, 4).Text
        officenumber.Value = f.Offset(0, 5).Text
        cellnumber.Value = f.Offset(0, 6).Text
     End With
   findnext
        FirstAddress = f.Address
Do
    s = s + 1
    Set f = range("A:A").findnext(f)
            Loop While Not f Is Nothing And f.Address <> FirstAddress
    If s > 1 Then
       Select Case MsgBox("There are " & s & " instances of " & Name, vbOKCancel Or vbExclamation Or vbDefaultButton1, "Multiple entries")

       Case vbOK
            findnext
        Case vbCancel
       End Select

    End If

Else: MsgBox Name & "Not Listed"
End If
End With

End Sub

Sub findnext()
 Dim Name As String
 Dim f As range
 Dim ws As Worksheet
 Dim s As Integer
 Dim findnext As range

   Name = surname.Value
   Me.ListBox1.Clear
     Set f = range("A:A").Find(what:=Name, LookIn:=xlValues)
     Set findnext = f

      With ListBox1
     Do
      Debug.Print findnext.Address
      Set findnext = range("A:A").findnext(findnext)
       .AddItem findnext.Value
       .List(0, 1) = findnext.Offset(0, 1).Value
       .List(0, 2) = findnext.Offset(0, 2).Value
       .List(0, 3) = findnext.Offset(0, 3).Value
       .List(0, 4) = findnext.Offset(0, 4).Value
       .List(0, 5) = findnext.Offset(0, 5).Value
       .List(0, 6) = findnext.Offset(0, 6).Value
       .List(0, 7) = findnext.Offset(0, 6).Value
   Loop While findnext.Address <> f.Address
       End With

End Sub
```

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa221353(v=office.11).aspx

Comment: Using [.Find And .FindNext](http://www.siddharthrout.com/2011/07/14/find-and-findnext-in-excel-vba/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to you `Find` then `FindNext` in a loop. You know you are done looping when your FindNext finds the very first thing you found again. It will cycle like that.

```
Dim firstFind As Range, subsequentFinds As Range

Set firstFind = Range("D3:D500").Find("search string", , xlValues)

Set subsequentFinds = firstFind
Do
    Debug.Print subsequentFinds.Address
    Set subsequentFinds = Cells.FindNext(subsequentFinds)
Loop While subsequentFinds.Address <> firstFind.Address
```

Comment: Isn't that what the above link demonstrate :) ?

Comment: @Brad I've added the loop but it's not working - i've re-edited the post

Comment: @SiddharthRout, yeah I guess so except I didn't see that before I answered and that's a comment not an answer.

Comment: @user1765813 you are reusing the results of the first find, not the findnext when populating your listbox. `AddItem f.Value` should be `AddItem findnext.Value`

Comment: @Brad: Yes it is a comment but to a link which explains IN DETAIL on how to use .Find/FindNext

Comment: @SiddharthRout, It's a great link. I just didn't see it until you pointed it out. I'm sorry if I'm stepping on your toes.

Comment: No you are not stepping on my toes :) But anyways point taken `I just didn't see it until you pointed it out.`

Comment: @Brad I've changed it to findnext but it messes up the list box values - for example, instead of showing surname|name|title it starts showing e-mails - not sure why it's doing that?

Comment: @Brad nvm i got it i changed the range so that only column 1 is searched and reported. thanks

Comment: just a quick question - the loop works but for the 2nd instance it doesn't show the full information in the listbox but it only shows name. it works fine with the first instance but the 2nd name it finds it doesn't show the information. do you know how i can fix this?

Comment: @user1765813 you'd have to post some data sample data. Enough data and code to reproduce your error.

Comment: @Brad I've posted my coding!